# How to incorporate VB Script Editor in Win App

Tags: c#, vb.net, editor

I created a Script Editor in a Windows Application using a RichTextbox and Regex for adding the colors for the coding. However it is not close to the Real VB editor. Is there some real good examples out there of how to build one or some free downloads?